# monerod advertise different external ip

Tags: monerod

I would like to run Monero on Kubernetes and the monerod's source-nat IP-address is not the same as the loadbalancer accepting incoming connections. Is there a way I can advertise to peers to connect back to this different loadbalancer-ip? I'm looking for something similar to the bitcoind's --externalip option. Thank you.

Comment: monerod will connect to other nodes, and other nodes will place the incoming IP address in their peer table, and this will be propagated throughout the monero network. Are you saying your outgoing connections seem to be coming from IP1, but incoming connections need to connect to IP2 ?